# Diagnosing tcp communication along a route

Tags: apache, networking, tcp, firewall

From my home DSL network I can no longer access a specific website (say www.example.com). 
Using wireshark and other tools, I observe the following properties:

1. when a request is sent to the site's port 80, the original TCP SYN gets no SYN/ACK answer
2. this happens for all platforms (Windows, iOS)
3. the web server (www.example.com) responds when the request comes from another IP (eg. from my workplace the website works OK)
4. the home network can access all other website on the net (so the home network works OK except for that site)
5. other web sites hosted at the same IP also don't answer
6. communication on other ports (eg. FTP, port 21) to the servers's IP works
7. Ping and tracert are succesful
8. No request is logged in the high-level server logs

Analysis: The above makes me believe, that there must be a firewall filtering out the requests along the route but only for requests on port 80. I see several options where this firewall could be located

1. in the modem at home
2. implemented by my ISP on their leg of the route (are they blocking that site for some reason)?
3. at the server (it's not serving my public IP for some reason)

As you'd expect, the ISP and the server hosting company each put the fault on the other. I want to investigate, where the problem lies.

**Question: how can I diagnose until where the original SYN message goes?**

- Is it blocked at the modem?
- does it reach the server?
- does the server answer (SYN/ACK), and the answer gets blocked / dumped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions first:

1) A **MODEM** does not block, filter, etc., a router will. If you have a router, and have access to the interface, you will be the one to determine whether or not your equipment is filtering.

2) Only the server's admin will be able to tell you this information.

3) See above.

NOW... As someone who maintains who knows how many servers, I from time to time block in on specific ports from specific destinations. For example, if I see a "known website spammer" (via Spamhaus, Shadowserver, etc), I have applications in place to re-write firewall rules. E.g., if $BAD_USER tries to access PORT80 then ipfw (firewall him from that port). So there is a possibility that your IP, or IP space as a whole (CIDR) is blacklisted from the server.

If you're on Linux or BSD you can try tcptraceroute:

```
tcptraceroute www.this-site.com 80
```

Where it **may** give you an indication of what is going on. It is not in the best interest for ISPs to arbitrarily block anything regardless of what one thinks. (At least here in the US its not). Blocking/filtering place burdens on equipment that must process those rules (check if this packet is in rule 1, nope, rule 2, nope). ISP equipment (core) is meant to pass out as fast as it comes in. Not "sit and process this packet for N amount of users"

Comment: Thanks, I will try tcptraceroute on a linux and report back.

Comment: I tried tcptraceroute, it gives me only "* * *" answers for every node except for the second on the route. Is my understanding correct, that this only probes whether the routers along the way also respond to port 80? If that's the case, it's probably not an interesting information anyway.

Comment: * * * could mean a lot of things: a) No hostname available (could not perform an nslookup (reverse name)) b) firewall/filtering means little as long as you get to your destination. If I had to guess, the end point (server you are trying to connect to) has some form of filtering in place.

Comment: (From the OP) The connection now works again, pretty exactly one month after it dropped off. I guess it was a dynamic filter which has was blocking the traffic. Neither me (on the modem/router) nor the ISP,  nor the server hosting did anything to change something.

Accepting your answer, although it did not really solve my problem.